# DNS CNAME Records For Multiple Websites

Tags: web-server, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 and have setup 2 websites in IIS8, and assigned to the IP address of the server (it only has one). They are both using port 80 as well.

How do I setup DNS records on the server so that the traffic is routed correctly? I can't find any information on the process on IIS8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I setup DNS records on the server so that the traffic is routed correctly?

You do not. DNS only can point a domain name to an IP. Or multiple domains to the same IP.

What you are looking for is the BINDING in IIS - where you tell which HOST NAME (domain name) gets routed to which website. DNS is at that point not involved at all - that time in the request has long long passed.