# IIS8 Website Binding Setup

Tags: windows-server-2012, website

I am having trouble trying to get IIS bindings working on my Windows Server 2012 box. I have access to the default IIS webpage, and am trying to add more websites to be hosted on the box. These are the settings I set with the additional sites:

- **Sites: Add Site**
- Site Name = Test Website (not my real domain name... obviously).
- Physical path = *path to folder containing the html file*
- Binding:

  - Type = http
  - IP Address = All unassigned (note, I have tried setting it to the IP address of the server as well)
  - Port = 80
  - Host name = www.test.com (not my real domain name, obviously).

From the research I have done, this should be all that is needed to make the external site visible from the address test.com

I have rebooted the server after setting up the new site as well, but still no luck. Intranet links to the 2nd site work fine.

Can someone please let me know what step I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, have you configured DNS?

As in - www.test.com must point to the IP of your server. If the request never arrives at the server - then - ah - all the IIS config is useless.

The rest is perfect.

Oh, and - rebooting is not needed ;) Not even IIS restarting.

Comment: I was told that http://serverfault.com/questions/566777/dns-cname-records-for-multiple-websites it wasn't necessary? I have tried to find information on how to setup DNS - but the information I found hasn't worked.

Comment: The answer was to setup DNS with a new A record against the site, and reference that into a CNAME record.